# Expandable rows in UITableView is set to be opened

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview

I have managed to make the TableView expandable. The problem is that when I start the app, it's always opened. I want it to be closed, and to be opened *just* when I hit the row.

What am I missing here? How can I set it to be open at start?

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 3;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 5;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (!indexPath.row)
    {
        // first row
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Expandable"; // only top row showing
     }
    else
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Some Detail";
        cell.accessoryView = nil;
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }
    return cell;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canCollapseSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first create a regular table with some array of booleans that holds the state of each row (open/close).

Then, when you hit a first row in a section, I reload the table with new rows:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    //subject hitted
    if (indexPath.row == 0)
    {
       // set relevant boolean here ,also , reload the table again with the new rows
       collapsedRows[indexPath.section]= ! collapsedRows[indexPath.section];
       [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
       //sub subject hitted
    else
    {

    }
}
```